# Base won't load in utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

So basically I am trying to follow these instructions https://dev.realworldocaml.org/install.html

I followed them literally. I have a working utop. I have a working VS Code environment. I can run code and everything.

We know the Base package is more efficient than the stdlib one for different reasons. For example:

In stdlib, to check if a member of a list exists, we do

```
List.mem "a" ["a"];;
```

in Base (for docs, look here https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.12/doc/base/Base/List/index.html), we do something like this:

```
open Base
List.mem ["a"] "a" ~equal:String.equal;;
```

When I do the last in utop, I get the following error: `Error: Unbound module Base'

Now, surely Base exists, when I try to install it via `opam install Base` it gives `Package base is already installed (current version is v0.15.1).` but it won't load, what is the problem?

When I do `#require "Base";;` in utop, it says `No such package: Base` and when I do `#require "base";;` it loads, now I have no idea what s going on really.

Answer (score 1):

Modules start with capitals, but the library is referenced with a lowercase letter. We can see the same with ocamlfind.

```
$ ocamlfind query base
/home/wtd/.opam/5.0.0/lib/base
$ ocamlfind query Base
ocamlfind: Package `Base' not found
```

Or in dune.

```
(executable 
  (name main) 
  (libraries base ...))
```

One way of ensuring the Base module is available in utop is to launch utop with: `utop -require base`.

---

Now for opinion territory: The Base library is different from Stdlib, but more efficient is a judgment you may be too new to the language to make. The example you presented for `List.mem` is more flexible in Basr than in Stdlib, because the function for determing equality can be provided as an argument, but for this simple case it makes the call to `List.mem` longer for no benefit.

Now, maybe the Base user wants to check for equality without case coming into play. They might write:

```
List.mem ["a"] "A" ~equal:String.Caseless.equal
```

But using Stdlib I might write:

```
List.exists (fun s -> String.uppercase_ascii s = "A") ["a"]
```

That's not awful.

Comment: so you mean `Base` is not installed? but then why in https://dev.realworldocaml.org/install.html they assume it s working by default. I am very confused.

Comment: From what you've said, it is, and your only hangup is `#require "base"` vs. `#require "Base"`.

Comment: but the book seems to talk about `base` to mean `Base`, can you redo the installation or investigate a bit. This should make a good answer for future learners. The book is famous in classrooms.

Comment: This isn't one of those things you can change. Consider another common library: `Lwt`. `#require "lwt"`  Run `opam list` and all of those libraries show up with lowercase letters.

Comment: But surely there is something just I didn't get and I can resolve it but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Easily done: add `#use "topfind";;` before `#require "Base";;` then `open Base`